# R: How to handle times without dates?

Tags: r, date, time, r-faq

I have data which includes `Date` as well as `Time enter` and `Time exit`. These latter two contain data like this: `08:02`, `12:02`, `23:45` etc.

I would like to manipulate the `Time eXXX` data - for example, substract `Time enter` from `Time exit` to work out duration, or plot the distributions of `Time enter` and `Time exit`, e.g. to see if most entries are before 10:00, or if most exits are after 17:00.

All the packages I've looked at require a date to precede the time, e.g. `01/02/2012 12:33`.

Is this possible, or should I simply append an identical date to every time for the sake of calculations? This seem a bit messy!

Comment: Related: [Convert hour:minute:second (HH:MM:SS) string to proper time class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034424/convert-hourminutesecond-hhmmss-string-to-proper-time-class)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `"times"` class found in the [chron package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/index.html):

```
library(chron)

Enter <- c("09:12", "17:01")
Enter <- times(paste0(Enter, ":00"))

Exit <-  c("10:15", "18:11")
Exit <- times(paste0(Exit, ":00"))

Exit - Enter # durations

sum(Enter < "10:00:00") # no entering before 10am
mean(Enter < "10:00:00") # fraction entering before 10am

sum(Exit >  "17:00:00") # no exiting after 5pm
mean(Exit >  "17:00:00") # fraction exiting after 5pm

table(cut(hours(Enter), breaks = c(0, 10, 17, 24))) # Counts for indicated hours   
 ## (0,10] (10,17] (17,24] 
 ##      1       1       0 

table(hours(Enter))  # Counts of entries each hour
## 9 17 
## 1  1

stem(hours(Enter), scale = 2)
## The decimal point is at the |

##   9 | 0
##  10 | 
##  11 | 
##  12 | 
##  13 | 
##  14 | 
##  15 | 
##  16 | 
##  17 | 0
```

Graphics:

```
tab <- c(table(Enter), -table(Exit))  # Freq at each time.  Enter is pos; Exit is neg.
plot(times(names(tab)), tab, type = "h", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Freq")
abline(v = c(10, 17)/24, col = "red", lty = 2) # vertical red lines
abline(h = 0)  # X axis
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the confusion I have edited it a bit to clarify.

**New Edit:**

First, `chron` package and `strptime` with fixed format both work well as demonstrated in other answers. I just want to introduce `lubridate` a little bit since it's easier to use, and flexible with time format.

Example data

```
df <- data.frame(TimeEnterChar = c(rep("07:58", 10), "08:02", "08:03", "08:05", "08:10", "09:00"),
                 TimeExitChar  = c("16:30", "16:50", "17:00", rep("17:02", 10), "17:30", "18:59"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If all you want is to count how many entry time were later than 8:00, then you can compare the character directly. Below would should 5 entry time were later.

```
sum(df$TimeEnterChar > "08:00")
```

If you want more, personally, I like `lubridate` package when dealing with time data, especially timestamps with dates although it's not the focus of this post at all.

```
library(lubridate)
# Convert character to a "Period" class by lubridate, shows in form of H M S
df$TimeEnterTime <- hm(df$TimeEnterChar)
df$TimeExitTime  <- hm(df$TimeExitChar)
head(df)

sum(df$TimeEnterTime > hm("08:00"))
```

You can still compare the time.

**A little more about using them as numeric:**
I assume only minute-level time is wanted. Thus, I divided number of seconds by 60 to get number of minutes.

```
df$DurationMinute <- as.numeric( df$TimeExitTime - df$TimeEnterTime )/60
hist(df$DurationMinute, breaks = seq(500, 600, 5))

head(df)
  TimeEnterChar TimeExitChar TimeEnterTime TimeExitTime DurationMinute
1         07:58        16:30     7H 58M 0S   16H 30M 0S            512
2         07:58        16:50     7H 58M 0S   16H 50M 0S            532
3         07:58        17:00     7H 58M 0S    17H 0M 0S            542
4         07:58        17:02     7H 58M 0S    17H 2M 0S            544
5         07:58        17:02     7H 58M 0S    17H 2M 0S            544
6         07:58        17:02     7H 58M 0S    17H 2M 0S            544
```

You can simply plot a histogram to see the distribution of time duration between entry and exit.

You can also look at the distribution of entry/exit time. But some effort is needed to convert the axis.

```
df$TimeEnterNumMin <- as.numeric(df$TimeEnterTime) / 60
df$TimeExitNumMin  <- as.numeric(df$TimeExitTime) / 60

hist(df$TimeEnterNumMin, breaks = seq(0, 1440, 60), xaxt = 'n', main = "Whole by 1hr")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0, 1440, 60), labels = paste0(seq(0, 24, 1), ":00"))

hist(df$TimeEnterNumMin, breaks = seq(420, 600, 15), xaxt = 'n', main = "Morning by 15min")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(420, 600, 60), labels = paste0(seq(7, 10, 1), ":00"))
```

[image]

I did not polish the plot, nor make the axis flexible. Please do based on your needs. Hopefully, it helps.

**Below is old useless post:** (no need to read. kept so that comments don't look weird)

Came across a similar issue and was inspired by this post. @G. Grothendieck and @David Arenburg provided great answers for transforming the time.

For comparison, I feel forcing the time into numeric helps. Instead of comparing `"11:22:33"` with `"9:00:00"`, comparing `as.numeric(hms("11:22:33"))` (which is `40953` seconds) and `as.numeric(hms("9:00:00"))` (`32400`) would be much easier.

```
as.numeric(hms("11:22:33")) > as.numeric(hms("9:00:00"))  &  as.numeric(hms("11:22:33")) < as.numeric(hms("17:00:00"))
[1] TRUE
```

The above example shows 11:22:33 is between 9AM and 5PM.

To extract just time from the date or POSIXct object, `substr("2013-10-01 11:22:33 UTC", 12, 19)` should work, although it looks stupid to change a time object to string/character and back to time again.

Converting the time to numeric should work for plotting as @G. Grothendieck descirbed. You can convert the numbers back to time as needed for x axis labels.

Comment: I don't see the point of your answer. `hms("11:22:33") > hms("9:00:00")  &  hms("11:22:33") < hms("17:00:00")` works nicely, why do you feel that wrapping each individual piece in `as.numeric` is better?

Comment: @Gregor You are absolutely right. I guess the reason why I did so initially was that I was thinking of converting it back to time format for plotting. Now I realize I can just use `hour(hms("11:22:33"))` instead of doing the math. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend deleting this answer. It doesn't seem to add anything useful---just distracts from the other answers. If I'm wrong and there is something useful here, then the answer should be edited to highlight that.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like that work?

```
SubstracTimes <-  function(TimeEnter, TimeExit){
  (as.numeric(format(strptime(TimeExit, format ="%H:%M"), "%H")) + 
  as.numeric(format(strptime(TimeExit, format ="%H:%M"), "%M"))/60) -
  (as.numeric(format(strptime(TimeEnter, format ="%H:%M"), "%H")) + 
   as.numeric(format(strptime(TimeEnter, format ="%H:%M"), "%M"))/60)
}
```

Testing:

```
TimeEnter <- "08:02"
TimeExit <- "12:02"
SubstracTimes(TimeEnter, TimeExit)
> SubstracTimes(TimeEnter, TimeExit)
[1] 4
```

Comment: This works for adding/subtracting, and returns decimal hours (i.e. 3.5 rather than 3:30). For plotting, perhaps I could manually assign values to bins in order to plot frequency of enter against time.

Comment: Maybe provide some example dataset and explain exactly what you want to plot and what is the expected result