# How to store time information in R without YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: r, date

All the answers that I've found for this question have to do with ggplot2 and other plotting applications. I'd like to know how I can store time information as a date-time object without extraneous date information.

E.g.:

```
strptime("09:13", format = "%H:%M")
```

becomes

```
"2014-03-26 09:13:00"
```

For my application the default date stamp is irrelevant, and since I'm doing calculations over a large array it actually just adds a lot of unnecessary data. How do I get a date-time object that looks like this instead?:

```
"09:13:00"
```

Comment: Could you convert it to character and use `strsplit`?  or do you need to keep it class `Date`?

Comment: Good thought, Richard. Since I want to preserve the time-ordering I need to keep this field in Date class. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: No worries.  I know this is annoying.  I was trying something similar last night.

Comment: it seems like it should be fairly straight-forward, right? i've combed through all the POSIX, strptime, and as.Date documentation along with all the posts on this site and can't find a straight-forward answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659947/r-how-to-handle-times-without-dates/22665577#22665577

Comment: that's it, thanks. unfortunately then ggplot2 doesn't know how to automatically set an appropriate default scale for times, which would have been nice. guess you can't have your cake and eat it, too

Comment: Perhaps `scale_x_chron` is relevant for you?