# R- How to subset data within a time range without dates provided?

Tags: r, subset

I am a brand new R user. I have a very large amount of data over a range of time, with time in the first column increasing by 1/32 second increments. I want to extract the section of data that falls within a specific time range; for example, all of the data between 12:11:08PM and 12:11:11PM. However, the times in this column do not have any dates. Therefore, I could not figure out how to apply lubridate, POSIXct, or any other time functions since they all required dates. Is there a way for me to subset my data with a time only function? Thank you for your time.

```html
time           id  result  
  12:11:08     10  200
  12:11:09     11  276 
  12:11:10     12  398 
  12:11:11     13  299 
  12:11:12     14  192  
  12:11:13     15  392
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659947/r-how-to-handle-times-without-dates

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `POSIXct/POSIXlt` stores time with an origin from "1970-01-01" with you timezone. So originally if you set the

```
as.POSIXct("12:11:10",format="%H:%M:%S")
```

it returns a full date format

```
[1] "2016-05-24 12:11:10 EEST"
```

You can easily subset time using default date settings (in this example function shows records after the *"12:11:10"*

```
 df<-data.frame(time=c("12:11:08","12:11:09","12:11:10","12:11:11","12:11:12","12:11:13"), 
               id=c("10", "11","12","13","14","15"),
               result=c("200","276","398","299","192","392"))

df[as.POSIXct(df$time,format="%H:%M:%S")>as.POSIXct("12:11:10",format="%H:%M:%S"),]

     time id result
4 12:11:11 13    299
5 12:11:12 14    192
6 12:11:13 15    392
```

Another great solution is to use `chrone` library

```
library(chrone)
df[chron(times=df$time)>chron(times="12:11:10"), ]
```