# How can I extract a specific range of hours from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, range, extract, hour

I have a data frame in R  with 2 columns (date_time , temp) I want to extract all the temp for the day time (between 5:59 Am to 18:00 Pm). I firstly separated  date and times(hours) with this code:

```
Th$Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(Th$`date`,
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = ""),
format = "%H:%M")%>% as_tibble()

Th$Dates <- format(as.Date(Th$`date`,"%Y-%m-%d",
tz = ""), format = "%Y-%m-%d")%>% as_tibble()
```

and then I use following command to extract specific times:

```
Th_day<- Th[Th$Hours >= " 06:00 AM" & Th$Hours<= "18:00 PM",]%>% as_tibble()
```

But I get a `tibble` that give rows from 00:00 to 18:00 for every day :

What is the problem ?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Th)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Th, 20))`.

Comment: There's an option below the question.

Comment: No, post the output of **`dput`** in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65670874/edit), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't separate out the date from the time. When you use `format` to get the time, you are converting it to a `character` class, that doesn't know how to do time-based comparisons with `>` and `<`.

Instead, use `hour` to extract the hour component as an integer, and do comparisons on that:

```
library(lubridate)
Th %>% 
  mutate(DateTime <- as.POSIXct(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "")) %>%
  filter(hour(DateTime) >= 6 & hour(DateTime ) < 18)
```

I'm making some assumptions about your data structure - if you need more help than this please edit your question to share some sample data with `dput()` as the commenters have requested. `dput(Th[1:5, ])` should be plenty.

Note that if you want to do a lot of operations on just the times (ignoring the date part), you could use the `times` class from the `chron` package, [see here for some more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22665577/903061).