# How to convert a column containing observations in STRING data type to TIME data type in r?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset in R named "may_2020_v1" that contains a column named "ride_time" in which the time observations are in character data type. I want to convert these observations into the standard time format of HH:MM:SS. Can anyone please help me out?

[image: Screenshot of the ride_time column]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: I tried to answer your question in a general way, since not much information was provided. I just noticed your screenshot. This is one way of providing information, but imo the worst way, since people cannot simply copy your data and test what they think could be the solution to your problem. For future questions, use the ```dput()``` function and copy-paste the output to your question (also look at how to format questions on stackoverflow). If you do it this way, people here can understand the problem better and give better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a string like "09:37:46" to a time datatype, you can use e.g. the `as.POSIXct()` function described [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.POSIX*). Depending on how you wrote the times in your strings, you can set the `format` option to make the function recognise your time format.
For example*:

```
as.POSIXct("11:28:31", format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Another option would be the `strftime()` ([description here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime)).

*note that in this case, the function will have to make some assumptions, e.g., the date and time zone, since those were not provided in the string. It would be better to call the function like this: `as.POSIXct("2021-05-29 11:28:31 CEST")`.

If you don't have a date for your time, you can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659947/r-how-to-handle-times-without-dates) and similar questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `{hms}` package can help here:

```
library(hms)

times <- hms::parse_hms(c("10:3:52", "10:47:11", "16:27:36", "13:17:24"))
times
10:03:52
10:47:11
16:27:36
13:17:24
```