# R splitting time date character to date and time

Tags: r

I have a character containing both time and date and I would like to split it into date and time.
I tried:

```
datetime <-  as.character("12:00:00 03-May-2019")
date1 <- as.Date(datetime ,"%d/%m/%Y")
date1

time1 <- as.Date(datetime ,%H:%M:%S)
time1
```

but I just get NA returned.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` should match the ones in the initial `vector`.

```
as.Date(datetime, "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "2019-05-03" "2018-05-03" "2017-05-03"
```

---

If the intention it to split by space `" "`

```
strsplit(datetime, "\\s+")
```

Or with `read.table`

```
df1 <- read.table(text = datetime, header = FALSE, col.names = c("time", "date"))
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%d-%b-%Y")
df1
#       time       date
#1 12:00:00 2019-05-03
#2 02:01:00 2018-05-03
#3 11:00:22 2017-05-03
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(datetime) %>% 
    separate(datetime, into = c('date', 'time'), sep=" ")  %>% 
    mutate(time = dmy(time))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  date     time      
#  <chr>    <date>    
#1 12:00:00 2019-05-03
#2 02:01:00 2018-05-03
#3 11:00:22 2017-05-03
```

#### data

```
datetime <-  c("12:00:00 03-May-2019",
           "02:01:00 03-May-2018",
           "11:00:22 03-May-2017")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will extract the date (as a `Date` object) and the time (as a character string). See [this post and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460608/want-only-the-time-portion-of-a-date-time-object-in-r) for some motivation for keeping the time as a character string.

```
extract_date_time <- function(dt){
  dt_split <- strsplit(dt, split=" ")
  lapply(dt_split, function(dts){
    list(date=as.Date(dts[2], '%d-%b-%Y'), time=dts[1])
  })
}
```

Example usage:

```
datetime <- as.character("12:00:00 03-May-2019")
extract_date_time(datetime)
```

You can also apply this function to a longer vector of strings like the one you originally have, like this:

```
datetimes <- c("12:00:00 03-May-2019",
               "02:01:00 03-May-2018",
               "11:00:22 03-May-2017")
extract_date_time(datetimes)
```